# How to create an entry in my dimensions in Business Central

Tags: dynamics-business-central

I have a dimension, which I would like to add another value.

I can list all my values through GET companies(id)/dimensions(id)/dimensionValues, but how can I add one to the list. POST does not work here

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible based on standard API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/resources/dynamics_dimensionvalue